# Writing nested dictionary slows down drastically

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary, bigdata

My Python code writes a nested dictionary from a table in SQLite. The table has around 40 Million rows. It processes 1 Million rows in about 30-60 seconds.

After it reached ~90% (36 Million rows), it slowed down and is not printing anything anymore without raising any errors.

The code :

```
selection_query = "Select * From my_table"
cursor = conn.cursor()
Cursor.execute(tbl)

dictionary = {}
Counter_1 = 0
row_nr = 0
for row in Cursor: 
      dict_key_1 = str(row[0])
      dict_key_2 = str(row[1])
      value = row[5]
      Counter_1 += 1
      row_nr += 1
      if dict_key_1 not in dictionary:
          dictionary[dict_key_1]={}
    
      dictionary[dict_key_1].update({dict_key_2 : value})
      if Counter_1>1000000:
        print(str("{00:.3%}".format(row_nr/4000000)) + str(datetime.now()))
        counter=0
```

Why did it suddenly slow down so drastically?

Comment: If your code really is building a dict which effectively stores the values for the last incidence of each key, might it be easier to write a query that selects the "last" row with each key rather than iterating over 40m records?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and advice! The first Version of this Code was actually as you suggested. Unfortunately, I had to change it and iterate over 40m lines, because the selection query for each "last" for 500,000 different "last values" was extremely slow. After running this code for 2-3 hours, a memory exception was thrown. So I decided to use a temporary approach that erases the obsolete dictionary keys to create more space in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Well i think you've got a problem with the memory here. Printing that many lines on the console uses a lot of memory of your rams (if it takes 100 Bytes per line then it would take about 400 MB ~ 500 MB). Your PC may say that this app is using up too much memory and stops it.